# Scroll with page after element is passed by

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, element

The title sounds a little strange.

I have a `<div>` I want to make this div to move or be pushed by the top of the browser once it's about to go out of sight.

An example would be the YouTube video manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in some jQuery plugins which provides sort of sticky divs. 
Have a look on http://blog.echoenduring.com/wp-content/uploads/demos/echo_ContainedStickyScroll/ or http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/floatobject for instance.